# Flutter app crashes after update on startup in Android

Tags: flutter

My app is experiencing the crash below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tech.vgts.lmes, PID: 4228
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/auth/internal/InternalAuthProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:78)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:71)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:468)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:354)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.InternalAuthProvider
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:78) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:71) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:468) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:354) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.instantiate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:78) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discover(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:71) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:468) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:354) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my dependency from:

```
firebase_auth:
```

to:

```
firebase_auth: 0.11.1
```